# How to integrate dialogflow in android apps

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, android-recyclerview

I want to integrate my chatbot(created by dialogflow) to my apps and I have create the xml files but I didn't find a way how to match between them. 
I have already database using room library persistance .And, I'm coding with Java.

How can I itegrate my agent into my apps?And how to add a recylerViewAdapter for my chatmessages.
Thank you

msg_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Hello this is me!!"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:background="@drawable/left_background"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Hi!! How are you!!"
    android:background="@drawable/right_background"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Chatbot.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Chatbot">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#f4f6f7"
        tools:listitem="@layout/msglist"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addBtn">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:hint="Type a Message"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back_fab"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fab_img"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
                android:tint="#fff"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

ChatbotActivity

```
public class Chatbot extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText message;
RelativeLayout addBtn;
ChatbotAdapter adapter;
Boolean flagFab = true;
private AIService aiService;
private AIServiceContext customAIServiceContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbot);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    addBtn = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String msg = message.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!message.equals("")) {

                ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(msg, "user");

            }

            message.setText("");

        }
    });


         adapter = new ChatbotAdapter();


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("Acces", 
     AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.French,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
    customAIServiceContext = AIServiceContextBuilder.buildFromSessionId("ID");
    aiService.setListener(this);

    final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(config);

    final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String msg = message.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!msg.equals("")) {

                aiRequest.setQuery(msg);
                new AsyncTask<AIRequest,Void, AIResponse>(){

                    @Override
                    protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {
                        final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
                        try {
                            final AIResponse response = 
                       aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                            return response;
                        } catch (AIServiceException e) {
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse response) {
                        if (response != null) {

                            Result result = response.getResult();
                            String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                        }
                    }
                }.execute(aiRequest);
            }
            else {
                aiService.startListening();
            }

            message.setText("");

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResult(AIResponse response) {

}

@Override
public void onError(AIError error) {

}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {
 }
}
```

Chatmessage

```
public class ChatMessage {

private String msgText;
private String msgUser;



public ChatMessage(String msgText, String msgUser){
    this.msgText = msgText;
    this.msgUser = msgUser;

}


public ChatMessage(){

}

//+getter & setter
}
```

ChatbotAdapter 
//I don't know how to code this class

```
 public class ChatbotAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatbotAdapter.ChatHolder> 
 {
@NonNull
@Override
public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.msglist, viewGroup, false);
    return new ChatHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatHolder chatHolder, int i) {
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class ChatHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView leftText, rightText;

    public ChatHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        leftText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leftText);
        rightText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightText);
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not that clear. Please add some more details like what is you want, what you have implemented and what issue is coming. 
You may also try my implementation. I am not using Recycler view in my implementation, but you could follow the following [article](https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-chatbot-with-dialogflow-8c0dcc8d8018) I wrote for integrating Dialogflow with Android. Try an follow the V2 version as V1 will phase out by October this year.
Also, Do not use fragment for Chatbot as it somehow does not work. Try and make a simple chatbot using my implementation and then you can work towards your own implementation.
Hope it works.

Comment: I've already seen your work but I didn't understood 
I've created an agent on Dialogflow and now I want to implement it on my apps. I want to create a simple conversation with the design I've mentionned.
I don't know how to integrate dialogflow

Comment: Please add details as I am not sure what is not working for you.

Comment: I will post the code that I'm using but I don't know how to code the adapter for the recyclerview

Comment: Firstly, edit your original question and add the code there. Remove your answer. Secondly, you are using V1 which is obsolete, move to V2. Thirdly, why are you using recycler view?

Comment: Why should I move to V2 ?. I’ve tried another code that’s why I used recyclerview

Comment: V1 will be removed completely by October as per Dialogflow Team. It will not be supported after that. In my example, both codes work the same way and you can avoid Recycler view.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is "R.raw.test_agent_credentials" and how to configure fulfillment ?

Comment: its a json file with account credentials. I have explained it on my medium post. Please check.

Comment: Glad it helped :)